# add a patch to an agentset and remove a patch from an agents

Tags: netlogo

I have questions regarding netlogo agentset operation looking for help, thx.

1. I want to add a patch, say patch-here, to a global agentset variable: mypatches. What is the correct way to write in a turtle procedure? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

   ```
   set mypatches (patch-set mypatches patch-here)
   ```
2. I want to remove a patch, say patch-here, from a global agentset variable: mypatches. What is the correct way to write in a turtle procedure? The following code doesn't work because one-of operator assumes to remove self (which is a turtle) from mypatches but what I want is to remove patch-here from mypatches.

   ```
   set mypatches one-of mypatches
   ```

Comment: Hi - welcome.  I've edited your post slightly so that the code appears differently from the rest of your writing.  To do this yourself, you just need to indent it a bit extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Appending patches

`patch-set` expects a patch agentset, so you have to
initialize `mypatches` to an empty set before adding first patches:

```
set mypatches no-patches
```

#### Remove a patch

You can filter with `with`:

```
set mypatches mypatches with [[patch-here] of myself != self]
```

Maybe more elegant and not so "self-confusing" solution is to ask a `patch-here` to do it with `other`:

```
ask patch-here [set mypatches other mypatches]
```

Comment: And is there any way to add a patch to a patch-set ?